# search if function user form

Tags: excel, vb.net

The code below is a if statement but with search combined. For example if the value of cell $BA$1 is found (partly or entirely, hence 'search' instead of equal) in column D, then enter the content of the cell $AZ$1 in col J. Otherwise enter the value of cell $AY$1. My VBA below returns correctly if the first condition is satisfied (eg $AZ$1) however, it returns #Value! instead of the value in $AY$1. 
There doesn't seem to be a syntax error and I've tried various ways of writing this line of code. Can you see where the issue is below please? let me know if this is not clear enough. thanks

```
  With Sheets("XXXX")
  With .Range("D2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 6)
    .Formula = "=IF(SEARCH($BA$1, D2, 1),$AZ$1,$AY$1)"
  End With
  End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Search` does not return `zero` or `false` in case of no match, it returns an error. So the appropriate test for a match should be either

- check for error using `IF(ISERROR(...),value-if-error,value-if-ok)` but then you'll need to reverse the order of your results:

  ```
  .Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH($BA$1, D2)),$AY$1,$AZ$1)"
  '               ^^^^^^^^                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```
- or check if the search's result is a number, using `ISNUMBER`. This will not change the order of your results. I usually prefer this option:

  ```
   .Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($BA$1, D2)),$AZ$1,$AY$1)"
   '               ^^^^^^^^
  ```

p.s. the third parameter (start-position) of `SEARCH` is `1` by default, so I omitted it.